# Changing the ∀ quantifier to the ∃ quantifier

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am tasked with **changing the $\forall$ quantifier** **with the $\exists$ quantifier**. However, I am not sure, whether I understood it correctly, and would like to ask for help.

As I understood, **the overarching rule is**: $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}:p(x)$ **is equal to** $\neg(\exists x \in\mathbb{Z}):\neg(p(x))$

**Applying this rule to two examples:**

1. $\exists x\in\mathbb{N}$ **,** $\forall y\in\mathbb{Z}$ **:** x-y²x=0. When replacing the $\forall$ quantifier: $\exists x\in\mathbb{N}$ **,** $\neg(\exists y\in\mathbb{Z})$ **:** x-y²x≠0. Further, this statement is True for x = 0
2. $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}$**,** $\forall y\in\mathbb{Z}$ : $yx\in\mathbb{N}$. When replacing the $\forall$ quantifier **two times**: $\neg(\exists x\in\mathbb{N}$),$\neg(\exists y\in\mathbb{Z}$): $\neg(yx\in\mathbb{N}$). Further, this statement is false for all y < 0.

Especially, in the second example I am unsure whether two replacements will result in $\neg(yx\in\mathbb{N}$) **or** $(yx\in\mathbb{N}$)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer “$\forall x \in N$” quantifies all that follows. So all that follows must be negated, and then that negation can ripple inwards. In your case, replacing the outer *for all* in $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}$**,** $\forall y\in\mathbb{Z}$ : $yx\in\mathbb{N}$ with a *there exists* yields
$$\neg\exists x\in\mathbb{N}: \neg(\forall y\in\mathbb{Z} : yx\in\mathbb{N}),$$
which, we can see by now applying that inner negation, amounts to
$$\neg\exists x\in\mathbb{N}: (\exists y\in\mathbb{Z} : yx\not\in\mathbb{N}).$$

When mathematicians write in the real world, we often slightly abuse the terminology of quantification, saying things like “For all $x \in \bf N$ and $y \in \bf Z$…”. But the same rules of logic apply when negating, so in the negation of a statement quantified that way, one can replace the contracted *for all* with a contracted (and negated) *there exists*. In concept, this contraction is essentially the same thing as if we replaced the formal expression of your answer (above) by
$$\neg\exists (x,y)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z} : yx\not\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks!